# MS Access macro for exporting to Excel hits limit of 65k records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a macro (created with the macro wizard) which runs a number of queries and then outputs a table to excel. The table has more then the 65,000 records limit for exporting formatted tables. How can I export the table without formatting in the macro? Here is the error I receive after I run the macro.

[image]

Comment: Try `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` instead.

Comment: That works, but seems to crash the database occasionally. It seems to be unreliable?

Comment: What type of Excel file are you exporting to? .xls can only have 65,535 rows. Perhaps .xslx will do the trick as it accommodates more rows (if you haven't done that allready). Maybe even try .xlsb for a performance boost, as it reduces the file size and is considerably faster.

Comment: It is .xlsx. It was working perfectly before with the OutputTo method, I don't understand how that has changed. I would ideally like a way to simply ignore formatting when outputting, that would solve the problem. For the record, TransferSpreadsheet is working now, I still would like to know the solution though.

Comment: I had same problem and wrote MS-Access VBA code that gets around this quickly and simply and has no problems.  But if the question, as posted, is limited to macros, then my answer would not responsive to this question.  Let me know if you want me to post VBA code as an answer.

Comment: @pghcpa Any chances of you posting the code for the rest of us?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using access vba to export the records but have you thought about using a datalink to your query from excel and using the access vba to open the excel file and refresh the data table? this will definitely eliminate any issues with max rows and should not have any failure issues due to export size. If you need more info on how to do that let me know and I'll add more info here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code requested by Anthony Griggs above.  But it is a VBA solution, not a macro solution, so not directly responsive to the question as posted.  This was how I worked around the problem and have had this successfully in production for a long time.

Be sure to add the reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" (or current version for you) and also the "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" (or current version for you) before using this code.  The save changes and quit at the end are critical, otherwise it leaves Excel open in the background that you have to kill via task manager.

```
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

    xl.Visible = False
    xl.ScreenUpdating = False

    vcurfilename = "MyFilename.XLSX”

    Set xlWb = xl.Workbooks.Open(vcurfilename, 0, False, 5, "password", "password")

    rs.Open "Select * from qryMyAccessQuery", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    Set xlRange = xlWb.Worksheets("MyExcelSheetName").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0)
    xlWb.Sheets("MyExcelSheetName ").Range("a2:bq25000").ClearContents
    xlRange.Cells.CopyFromRecordset rs

    xl.Range("Table1").Sort key1:=xl.Range("Table1[[#All],[MyColumnName]]"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    On Error Resume Next
    xl.Range("table1").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    rs.Close

    xl.Range("table1").ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Find("MyColumnName1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"
    xl.Range("table1").ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Find("MyColumnName2").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"
    xl.Range("table1").ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Find("MyColumnName3").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yy"

    xlWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    xl.Quit
    DoEvents
```